# value is not getting populate through drool Decision table

Tags: spring-boot, drools

I want to incorporate a drool decision table in my spring boot 
     application with h2 data base. While I am starting the application the 
     value from drool VO getting null. There are seem to be an issue with H2 
     DB. If I remove the H2 from Maven then it start working. How to fix that 
      ? please suggest.

```
pom.xml:
 -----------------------------------------------------------------


<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>

                 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter- 
              tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-ci</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-decisiontables</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--spring integration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
        <artifactId>kie-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${drools-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <drools-version>7.21.0.Final</drools-version>
    <spring-framework.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
   </properties>

please suggest ....
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by replace the drool version to 7.24.0.t043 as it is resolved the issue for compatibility with dev tool( spring boot)